# Google Cloud Function: Access folders in a Google Storage bucket and process files from them

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm fairly new to GCP and I'm trying to write a Google Cloud Function that would be triggered by a new file once it appears in a bucket. I made this work, but the thing is that the Cloud Function is also supposed to perform another action: it needs to access a folder which is already present the bucket (that means, before the trigger happens: this folder is called `data_folders` and contains more folders -- `0_42_ten`, `1_42_ten`, `2_42_ten`; from the `data_folders` I want to access the `1_42_ten` one so I can load files from it).
My problem is I cannot set up the Cloud Function in a way it would "see" the `data_folders` folder.

Here's the code I'm using (I have re-written the code to focus on accessing the "old" folder only):

```
from google.cloud import storage
import glob


def hello_gcs(event, context):
     """Triggered by a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
     Args:
          event (dict): Event payload.
          context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
     """
     file = event
     print("Function triggered")
     storage_client = storage.Client()
     bucket = storage_client.bucket("bucket_name")
     blob = bucket.blob("bucket_name/data_folders")
     print(blob)

     def list_folders():
          path = 'bucket_name/data_folders'
          list_of_folders = glob.glob(path)
          sorted_folders = sorted(list_of_folders)
          print(sorted_folders)

     
     list_folders()
```

The Cloud Function gets deployed successfully but then (when I test it using the "testing" tab and passing `{"name": "data_folders"}` as an input) it returns an empty list (instead of ['0_42_ten', '1_42_ten', '2_42_ten'] or so), suggesting it doesn't "see" the `data_folders` nor the folders in it. I tried to play with the format of the path (e.g. `gs://bucket_name/data_folders`, `bucket_name/data_folders/*`, etc) but nothing worked.

Could someone please advise me on how to solve this?

Comment: is it `data_folder` or `data_folders` ?

Comment: `data_folders`, sorry for the typo

Comment: The bucket name must not be in the path. In addition, folders do not exist (it's a bucket blob storage model, all the file are stored at the root level, the file name is the full path. The `/` is a human readable separator for folders, but they have no physical reality!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments listing using `glob` does not work as it intended for local filesystem.

Thus the minimal example to list objects underneath some **virtual** folder in object storage on GCS (Google cloud storage) might look like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from google.cloud import storage
import os

BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv("BUCKET_NAME", "the-bucket")
BUCKET_PATH = os.getenv("BUCKET_PATH", "the-path")

print(f"BUCKET_NAME={BUCKET_NAME} BUCKET_PATH={BUCKET_PATH}")
print(f"via CLI: gsutil ls -l gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/{BUCKET_PATH}/")

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
content_list = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=f"{BUCKET_PATH}/"))
print(content_list)
```

**Please note**: that if the specified folder does not directly contain the objects (or blobs) then this function in case of GCS finds those down in the tree. That might be eventually in another level of folders.

So if the objects store there are having paths like:

`gcs://the-bucket/the-path/sub-folder/object.csv.gz`

This file gets listed by `bucket.list_blobs(prefix="the-path/")`

Comment: Seems like I misunderstood the concept of folders vs blobs. Your code worked perfectly, thanks a lot!